# K-means, but normalized and with max

Tags: approximation, clustering

Given points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in the Euclidean space and $K \in \mathbb N$, I'm interested in the following objective.
Partition the points into $K$ clusters $C_1, \ldots, C_K$ so that:
$$\max_{i \in [K]} \frac{1}{|C_i|}\sum_{j \in C_i} \|x_j - \mu(C_i))\|^2$$
is minimized, where $\mu(C_i) = \frac{1}{|C_i|} \sum_{j \in C_i} x_j$.
So it's similar to k-means, but it has $\max$ instead of sum, and the term for each cluster is normalized. Intuitively, I want to minimize $\max_i Var[C_i]$.

Does this problem have a name? Is there a known approximation for this problem?

Comment: Without normalization, the problem is known as the [Minimum Load Clustering problem](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3173047). In Euclidean space, it has been studied [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.09481.pdf). Overall, this problem has been barely studied. Therefore, less chance to find your version of the problem.